# Cypress testing framework is not installing using npm

Tags: cypress

I tried to install cypress using `npm install cypress --save-dev command` but after installing the following things do not execute.

I waited for more than 2 hours but the progress does not complete
[image]

Comment: How about write permissions into this dir right under C: drive?

Comment: I have permission in my C drive. Similarly, I tried in another drive and found the same problem